# How to install custom typings?

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-typings

I created a custom typing contains code that I would like to share across several webstorm node.js projects.  The issue is that I am trying to find documentation outlining how to include the typing in a project.  I tried to using the npm command but it did not add the folder to the @typings folder under /node_modules folder.  Also, when I compile the project that I am trying to add the custom typing to, I am getting duplicate errors for the mongoose library between the project that contains the typing and the project I would like to add the typing to.  I am not sure of what the problem could be.

tsconfig.json(for the new type):

```
{
  "name": "newcustomtype",
  "description": "...",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "./dist/index.js",
  "typings": "./dist/index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "grunt": "grunt"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.0.35",
    "@types/express-jwt": "0.0.34",
    "debug": "^2.2.0",
    "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^4.9.2",
    "tslint": "^4.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/mongodb": "^2.1.41",
    "@types/mongoose": "^4.7.9",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.10",
    "grunt": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-cli": "^1.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-ts": "^6.0.0-beta.15",
    "grunt-tslint": "^4.0.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
    "ts-node": "^3.0.2",
    "tslint": "^4.5.1",
    "typescript": "^2.2.1"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json(where the typing should be installed):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "ES5",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "types": ["reflect-metadata"],
    "lib": ["ES6"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "noLib": false
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false
}
```

I tried to follow the doc. on the typescript website but I have not been able to find a resource outlining how to install once created.  Although, for it to not install the custom typing, I think there is also a problem with my tsconfig files as well.  Please review and let me know what I am missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The `node_modules/@types` folder is only for definitions which get installed by npm. For custom typings it would be best to [specify `typeRoots`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types) within your `tsconfig.json`. For example:

```
{
  [...]
  "compilerOptions": {
    [...]
    "typeRoots" : ["../path/to/typings", "./node_modules/@types"],
    [...]
  }
  [...]
}
```