# how to declare a typings.ts file in angular build library

Tags: angular

I followed this tutorial to create a library for angular
https://medium.com/@tomsu/how-to-build-a-library-for-angular-apps-4f9b38b0ed11

Everything is working fine.
Now I want to use third party libraries. But I don't know where to tell angular to look for typings.d.ts and declare some types

```
declare var Foo: any;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do it:

A) simply make a file at the project root named global.d.ts and list your declare module 'x' statements all in that one file.

declare module 'third-party-library-name'

B)
1: Edit your tsconfig file to use the typeRoots property.

2: Add that root folder to the exclude property in the tsconfig file as well.

3: Add a folder for your third-party library in your types directory.

4: Add an index.d.ts file with your typings into that folder.

5: Add your type definition as declare module 'third-party-library-name'

Reference Links:
[How to add custom "typings" in typescript 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38971984/how-to-add-custom-typings-in-typescript-2-0)
https://www.detroitlabs.com/blog/2018/02/28/adding-custom-type-definitions-to-a-third-party-library/
[How to install custom typings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46008688/how-to-install-custom-typings)